# Visual Studio Load Test View Raw Results

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, load-testing, performance-testing

I am running a Coded UI test using Visual Studio load testing capabilities.

My test runs successfully, but I am trying to get a better understanding of results. My results are stored as "All Individual Details" and are stored in a local database. However, I'd like to extract raw results for each individual transaction. All I can really see in the results is the number of times each transaction ran, the average response time and the min and max etc. I'd like to get hold of the raw results for each individual transaction however. Is this possible?

I'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio stores load test results in an SQL database, provided the "run settings" specify so. The contents of the database for Visual Studio 2010 is defined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slumley/archive/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database.aspx). A few changes have been made for later versions but much remains the same.

Much of the contents of the database is derived from Web Performance tests but the question asks about load tests running Coded UI tests. Transactions and pages are features of Web Performance tests, whilst the author of a Coded UI test may think of transactions and pages, Coded UI has no inbuilt items that provide that data. Hence various parts of the database will be empty.

To find the connection string for the SQL load test database, open any load test file then from toolbar (or context menu) select "Manage Test Controllers". The connection string will be shown within the window.

Answer (score 0):

to get the raw data do the following, 
1.open the results 
2. select the graph tab
3. Select the drop down, e.g. transaction response time
4. In the top right corner, select Export graph data to excel